# Как отправить данные на сервер по клику?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

Не получается передать данные. Есть список городов:

```
<li><a href="#" id="post_btn">Белгород</a></li>
...
<li><a href="#" id="post_btn">Рязань</a></li>
```

При клике по ссылке на сервер должен передаваться post-запрос, содержащий тот город, на который кликнули. Пыталась сделать вот так:

```
<a href="#" onclick='$.post("index.php", {name: "Рязань"});'>Рязань</a>
```

Не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать.

Comment: что выдает? что в консоли? что в xhr запросах, которые можно посмотреть плагином firebug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, id у элемента должен быть уникальный, так что в Вашем случае нужно использовать класс:

```
<li><a href="#" class="post_btn">Белгород</a></li>
...
<li><a href="#" class="post_btn">Рязань</a></li>
```

Далее, вешаем обработчик для ссылок с нужным классом:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".post_btn").click(function() {
     name = $(this).text();
     $.post("index.php", {name: name});
  });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, я понимала, что не нужно помещать обработчик в тег, но не знала как передать текущее значение города в функцию. Не могли бы вы еще пожалуйста подсказать, не имеет значение указан абсолютный url или относительный? В данном случае запрос обрабатывает та страница, которая и отправляет.

Comment: Путь прописывается либо относительный, либо от корня. Абсолютный точно не нужен.

Answer (score 3):

Как верно замечено в ответе выше, это должно работать. Я бы посоветовал Вам воспользоваться замечательным расширением для Firefox, которое называется Firebug - очень облегчает отладку и тестирование клиентского кода. Ошибка у Вас, вероятнее всего, кроется в чем-то, что не указано в вашем куске кода. А еще небольшой совет - не помещайте обработчики событий внутри HTML-тэгов, javascript-код все же лучше отделять от разметки.